# package org.apache.s4.core.staging doesnot existing in latest S4 code‏

Tags: java

i was trying to use S4 (http://incubator.apache.org/s4/) in one of my project.

i downloaded the code by running

git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-s4.git

however i failed to see the package org.apache.s4.core.staging anywhere in the downloaded source. but i can still compile the code successfully.

this package seems exist in the lnk http://people.apache.org/~mmorel/apache-s4-javadoc/0.6.0/index.html?org/apache/s4/core/staging/ThrottlingRemoteSendersExecutorServiceFactory.html

can anyone tell me where is it?  thanks!!!!  or is that package deleted from the latest trunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone the git repo it'll be on the `piper` branch, which seems to be quite outdated (July 2012), for some reason.

Just `git checkout master` to get the main development branch, and you'll be able to find the `staging` package at `./subprojects/s4-core/src/main/java/org/apache/s4/core/staging`.